# Gauss map and image of projective variety $V : x^4+y^4+z^4=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I want to describe the Gauss map and find its image for the projective variety $V : x^4+y^4+z^4=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

I know the definition from the book 'An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry' of Springer:
$V \rightarrow Gr(d+1,n+1): p \mapsto T_pV$, where $T_pV$ is the projective tangent space to $V$ at the point $p$, and $d = dim(V)$ and $n=2$.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

This image of the Gauss map of a plane curve is usually referred to as the dual curve.

By Plücker's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_formula the dual of any smooth quartic curve has degree $12$, $28$ ODP singularities and $24$ cusp singularities. Given these facts, one assumes that the defining equation of the dual curve perhaps isn't anything too familiar.

The process of finding the equations of a dual curve is explained in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve#Properties_of_dual_curve.

For a point $[p:q:r]$ in the curve, the point $[X:Y:Z]$ in the dual projective space satisfies the four equations:

$$X = \lambda 4 p^3,   Y = \lambda 4 q^3 , Z = \lambda 4 r^3, Xp+Yq+Zr = 0.$$

In addition to the original defining equation of the curve. So eliminating the four variables $p,q,r,\lambda$ should allow you to get a defining equation.

Comment: +1, but there's an extraneous $\lambda$ in your final equations. If you're interested in what the equation is, see [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwL0rMp0CnUKdKJ0InUibJTsFUIyM-pzMvPzUzMCcrMS9cIDNQx0-Tl8gTKBCloKURH6JpoFcQZ6yhEAhmFIEYUkFEEYkRoFWhHahVqR2kVxfJyeQF1eOql5mTmZuYllmTm58VnpqQm5mhEg-2L1bRW8AIAi18jeQ==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) for a CAS-assisted computation which gives $$X^{12} + 3X^8Y^4 + 3X^4Y^8 + Y^{12} + 3X^8Z^4 - 21X^4Y^4Z^4 + 3Y^8Z^4 + 3X^4Z^8 + 3Y^4Z^8 + Z^{12}.$$